# How to determine the data count that is currently visible on the xaxis in coreplot

Tags: ios, objective-c, datasource, core-plot

How is it possible to determine the data offset that is currently shown in a graph made with coreplot.

I need to get the indices of my dataSource-array.

For example if I have a graph that's xRange is from 0 to 100 and I have 555 Datasets:

When the graph is not zoomed all 555 Datasets are displayed -> Index 0 to 554
When the graph is zoomed or paned not all datasets are displayed -> e.g. Index 100 to 333

My question is now how I can find out these index numbers (100 and 333) for the currently display lower and upper-bound of the graph. For example in the `- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space
      willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange
              forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate`-Delegate method

Comment: I found a solution. Now I add another hidden xaxis in its own plotspace. The range of this plotspace I set from 0 - data.count. Now i can grab the changed range of this axis after zooming and panning. If anyone got a better idea please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution only works if the data is sorted by index and evenly distributed along the x-axis. The general solution is to look at the plot range in the plot space delegate (either the old or new depending on what you're doing) and look at each data point to determine whether it falls in the plot range or not. If the data is sorted, evenly spaced, and you know the minimum and maximum values, it is a simple proportion calculation to determine the first and last index in the plot range.

Comment: " look at each data point" - Warning, this can get expensive with large vales of n.